# A quick, more elementary way to show $(\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong C_4 \times C_2$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof

What's a fast, elementary way to show $(\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong C_4 \times C_2$? I'm asking this question because in general I'd like to know if there's a nice way to tell what abelian group $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is isomorphic to quickly.

Currently, my best method is this: $|(\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}|=\varphi(16)=8$, hence $(\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is an abelian group of order $8$.

It has no element of order $8$ by Gauss' theorem classifying when $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic. Rule out $C_8$.

It has an element of order $4$: $3^2=9 \neq 1, 9^2=1$. Rule out $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.

Hence, it's $C_4 \times C_2$.

Using Gauss' theorem seems like quite high technology, so what's an elementary way to do the part "no no element of order $8$"? I could check all of them, but that's quite long.

Or is there a faster, completely different way?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure

Comment: Well, you have $16$ elements, you can check manually that none of them is of (multiplicative) order $8$. That won't use Gauss.

Comment: You can check directly that there are (at least) two elements of order $2$, so it cannot be cyclic: both $5^2$ and $-5^2$ have order $2$, with $5^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $-5^2\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, so $5^2\not\equiv -5^2\pmod{16}$.

Comment: If you can factor $n$ then it is straightforward to know what the unit group is isomorphic to... bit presumably you don't want to have to factor $n$, which is hardly "quick".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $n\geq 3$. Then $5$ has order $2^{n-2}$ modulo $2^n$ and $2^{n}$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides $5^{2^{n-2}}-1$.

*Proof.* We proceed by induction. For $n=3$, $5\not\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, but $5^2=25\equiv 1\pmod{8}$. Note moreover that $2^3\Vert 5^2-1$.

Assume $5$ has order $2^{n-2}$ modulo $2^n$ and that $2^{n}\Vert (5^{2^{n-2}}-1)$. Then $5^{2^{n-2}}= 1+k2^{n}$ for some odd integer $k$, but $5^{2^{n-2}}\not\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+1}}$.

Squaring we get
$$5^{2^{n-1}} = (1+k2^n)^2 = 1 + k2^{n+1}+2^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+1}},$$
so the order of $5$ modulo $2^{n+1}$ divides $2^{n-1}$, and is greater than $2^{n-2}$; thus, the order is precisely $2^{n-1}$. In addition, since $k$ is odd the largest power of $2$ that divides $5^{2^{n-1}}-1 = 2^{n+1}(k+2^{n-1})$ is $2^{n+1}$, completing the induction. $\Box$

Now note that all the powers of $5$ modulo $2^n$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$; The elements $-5$, $-(5^2),\ldots,-(5^{2^{n-2}})$ are all congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ and pairwise incongruent. In particular, there are two elements of order $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, namely $5^{2^{n-3}}$ and $-5^{2^{n-3}}$. So $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ cannot be cyclic.

Since $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n)^{\times}$ has order $2^{n-1}$, is abelian, is not cyclic for $n\geq 3$, and has an element of order $2^{n-2}$, it follows that it is isomorphic to $C_{2^{n-2}}\times C_2$.

Comment: I think there might be some ambiguity in what is meant by "elementary" here: "easy" vs. the mathematical sense of the word. You seem to capture both! (+1)

Comment: Does "$\Vert$" mean "divides"? I've never seen this before, if that's the case.

Comment: @citadel For a prime power $p^a$, $p^a\Vert n$ is commonly used to mean "$p^a$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$". That is, $p^a\Vert n\iff p^a\mid n$ and $p^{a+1}\nmid n$.

Answer (score 2):

Not exceedingly long, once you note that $(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z)^\times=$ $\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$ and:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&1^2\equiv 1\pmod{16} \\
&3^2\equiv \color\red{9}\pmod{16} \\
&5^2\equiv \color\red{9}\pmod{16} \\
&7^2\equiv 1\pmod{16} \\
&\color\red{9^2\equiv 1}\pmod{16} \\
&11^2\equiv \color\red{9}\pmod{16} \\
&13^2\equiv \color\red{9}\pmod{16} \\
&15^2\equiv 1\pmod{16} \\
\end{alignat}
whence the nontrivial elements of $(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z)^\times$ have order $2$ or $4$, so none have order $8$.

Comment: Thanks, but also I'm more looking for a method that can be done quickly for $(\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ for more general $n$ as stated in the question. This will get longer for larger $n$.

Comment: Fair enough  @Robin.